# Powershell workflow - Get-Service not filtering

Tags: powershell, workflow

I am trying to restart Windows services in parallel via Powershell workflow.
When I use `Get-Service -DisplayName "S*"` outside of workflow I get expected results.

However, when I use the same in workflow, I get ALL services instead. It seems that `-Displayname` parameter is ignored in workflow.

How do I get only wanted services in PS workflow?

Using script:

```
workflow Restart-Services(){
    $services = Get-Service -DisplayName "S*"

    Foreach -Parallel ($svc in $services){
        $name = $svc.Name
        Restart-Service -Name $svc -Force
    }
}

Restart-Services
```

Comment: read here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/01/30/powershell-workflows-using-parameters.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea why `-Name [wildcard]` works and `-DisplayName [wildcard]` doesn't (inside a workflow), but you can use `Where-Object` to accomplish the filtering if you like:

```
workflow Restart-Services{
    $services = Get-Service |Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.DisplayName -like "S*"}

    Foreach -Parallel ($svc in $services){
        $name = $svc.Name
        Restart-Service -Name $name
    }
}
```

Comment: How come if you don't include any of the letters in here, the workflow doesn't start? If there's `-FilterScript` missing, workflow throws ambiguous parameter set error on `Where-Object`. Just wasted 15 minutes with this.

Comment: @Vesper Yes I noticed that as well, haven't figured out what that's about. Maybe ambiguity due to workflow common parameters?

Comment: It has to do with the way workflows work in the back end.  Workflow's aren't interpreted by powershell, they're flattened into xml's and fed into the .net windows workflow foundation.  This is why you'll often see odd behavior.  To get around this I often employ `inlinescript{}` blocks (which are actually processed with the powershell engine).